# Как переводить такие секции на WP?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Делаю мультиязычный сайт на WP. Использую плагин Polylang + ACF. При создания новых страниц с переводами, просто передаю контент в админ панели и в зависимости от языка он сам подгружает контент на нужном языке.

НО на сайте есть секция которая повторяется абсолютно на всех страницах, секция с контактами. Если делать ее обычным способом, контент менеджеры должны будут на каждой странице заполнять заново эту секцию. Можно ли как то ее создать отдельно заполнить на всех языках и уже выводить?

Раньше я делал много полей и в коде делал проверку `if language == english` Выводи контент на английском , `else if language == russian` Выводи на русском. Но такой способ мне кажется не совсем корректным, ведь будет много языков и делать столько проверок очень сложно.

Хотелось бы иметь возможность заполнить эту секцию в одном месте и в зависимости от языка, WP сам выводил нужный контент как с другими страницами( **Использую Polylang** )

Comment: Создайте новый тип данных, типа "Текстовые блоки", а потом вызывайте одним кодом где нужно, передавая идентификатор языка, в лучшем случае, что-то вроде сниппета.

Comment: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-and-polylang/ https://polylang.pro/doc/working-with-acf-pro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Polylang есть специальный функционал для таких случаев. Называется String Translation. Вам нужно будет вывести ваш статичный текст в шаблоне таким образом:

```
<?php pll_e('Site Title'); ?>
<?php pll_e('Site Description'); ?>
```

И зарегистрировать строки в файле functions.php

```
add_action('init', function() {
  pll_register_string('mytheme-name', 'Site Title');
  pll_register_string('mytheme-name', 'Site Description');
});
```

После этого он появится в разделе "Перевод строк" плагина Polylang.

Если вам удобнее использовать поля ACF для этого - то как решение создать страницу опций ACF и в ней поля на русском и английском языках, указывая в имени поля языковой код, например так `title_en` и `title_ru` и затем выводить их таким образом:

```
 <?php the_field('title_' . pll_current_language()); ?> 
// pll_current_language() - возвращает код активного языка (ru или en, например)
```

Answer (score -1):

Для этого, сделайте так: добавьте в functions.php след код:

`if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    acf_add_options_page( array(
        'page_title'    => 'Опции сайта',
        'menu_title'    => 'Опции сайта',
        'menu_slug'     => 'site-options',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false
    ) );
}`

В админке появится пункт меню "Опции сайта". 
После, создайте новую группу полей и назовите ее "Страница опций" (можно любое название). Группы полей -> Добавить. В условиях отображения: "Отображать группу полей, если" выбрать "Страница с опциями" равно "Опции сайта".
Далее здесь же создаете нужные вам поля для контактов, поле для одного языка и поле для друго языка. Сохраняете.

После, переходите в админке в раздел "Опции сайта". Заполняете созданные поля.

Теперь, на странице шаблона( php файл ), где вам нужно вывести доп поля со страницы опций, вставляете код вот так `the_field('название поля', 'option')`.